# Unable to read formData correctly server-side in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, multipartform-data

I use [JQuery Fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload files from my view to the server in .NET. I tried to add additional information to the upload, which are values of two combobox in the page. I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data) and decided to add my combobox values in `formData` programmatically. However, it's dont work as intended.

Here is my `fileuploader`:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
  sequentialUploads: true,
  multipart: true,
  formData: { SectorCode: $('#comboSector').val(), AppName: $('#comboApp').val() },
  autoUpload: true,
  done: function (e, data) {
    $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
    $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
    $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
  }
})
```

And here is my `controller function`:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult UploadFiles(string data)
    {
        string sector = Request.Form["SectorCode"];
        string app = Request.Form["AppName"];
    .....
    }
```

The problem here is that sector and app both return null. However, if I choose to pass  `{SectorCode: 3, AppName: myApp}`, I will have the good values server side. What is wrong here?

EDIT:

Here is my relevant HTML part:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple accept="application/pdf">
```

Comment: are you using ASP.NET server controls ?

Comment: did you try to add quotation marks?
`"\"" + $("#comboSector").val()+"\""`

Comment: Yes, I tried this! @Legends

Comment: Try this: `JSON.stringify(
  { SectorCode: $('#test').val(), AppName: $('#test2').val()}
)`. You have to parse it on the server, because it will be a string.

For older browser's who don't support JSON natively you have to use JSON2.js.

Comment: formData can't accept this, according to the doc it can be written like that

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, ensuring that the form elements have the name property defined:

```
string sector = Request.Form["comboSector"];
string app = Request.Form["comboApp"];
```

and skip the `formData` property altogether.

If not, post your html please?

Comment: I added the HTML. My input is not in a form

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest to use following usage.

Your Html, (Attention to file input name. It should match in the model)

```
<select id="SectorCode" />
<select id="AppName"/>
<!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" multiple>
```

Create a model for your action

```
public class FormData
{
    public List<HttpPostedFileWrapper> files { get; set; }
    public string SectorCode { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
}
```

And define your controller action like this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFiles(FormData data)
{
    ...
}
```

In order to append additional form data use fileuploadsubmit event

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = '@Url.Action("Upload","Home")';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            // handle done event.
        },
    }).bind("fileuploadsubmit", function (e, data) {
        data.formData = {
            SectorCode: $("#SectorCode").val(),
            AppName: $("#AppName").val()
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: You don not need to define model for the action. Just use IFormFile when defining your controller action.

Comment: @GratsielaGeshewa Yes in .Net Core MVC you can use IFormFile but in .Net Framework one had to use [HttpPostedFileWrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilewrapper?view=netframework-4.8), and also if you need to send additional data in form body you would probably need a Model class to wrap other properties.